# Spring Data REST example that doesn't use root for mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I cannot figure out where to modify the Spring Data REST service so that it is NOT in root /

I'm looking over the JavaDoc for RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration , but if anyone has an idea I'd appreciate some guidance.

**My webConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

}
```

If I can I'd like to write a how-to on getting this working, but not finding anyone else using non root.. ie http:// server /servicename/entity?foo=bar

Tried modifying servlet initializer too, but nothing.

**My webAppInitializer.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/servicename" }; 
    }

}
```

Result from attempting to hit the service

```
Welcome to the REST shell. For assistance hit TAB or type "help".
http://server:8080:> discover
http://server:8080/servicename Command failed
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
http://server:8080/servicename:>
```

**EDIT: Tomcat failed to deploy my Spring Data Rest servlet**
hence the service isn't responding.

Now trying to figure out why this occurred :

```
13:16:55.806 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'appConfiguration'

13:16:55.814 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class whichdegree.webmvc.AppConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean whichdegree.webmvc.AppConfiguration.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class whichdegree.webmvc.AppConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource whichdegree.webmvc.AppConfiguration.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database type [HSQL] is not available in the classpath
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.M3.jar:4.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.M3.jar:4.0.0.M3]
>...
```

**EDIT 2 : added hsqldb.jar to classpath. Service now running but servlet.init still threw an  exception**

I'm going to do some more research on HSQL, and see if I can't solve this exception myself.  Will mark the relevant answer regarding mapping as correct and open a new question for this exception below if I need to.

```
 exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter' defined in class whichdegree.webmvc.WebConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter.getReturnValueHandlers()Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite;
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:665)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:512)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter.getReturnValueHandlers()Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite;
    org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter.java:26)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1503)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:665)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:512)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead usage of this kind of pattern:

```
"/servicename/*"
```

This kind of structure was introduced in another answer on SO, see my reference.

*It is part of the un-accepted solution there, there the pattern was  `"/rest/*"` which were used for a `rest` sub url path.*

**Source**

[1] [SpringDataRest and show welcome-file-list/disable link discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251728/springdatarest-and-show-welcome-file-list-disable-link-discovery)

Comment: actually, I looked inside tomcat logs.. my service failed to start... will edit to append log file.

Comment: According to the edit, you don't have hsqldb.jar on your server log folder or the containing folder is not included to your classpath definition in conf/catalina.properties file.

Comment: you were SPOT ON, I just realized you need to do a bunch of setup for HSQL (which was never explained in any of the tutorials, makes me want to write my own but don't know where)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the Hibernate driver class for your particular database vendor on your classpath. Can you post the configuration of your Hibernate data source?

Comment: I'm pretty much brand new to hibernate.  Since i was using HSQL (an in memory DB) I didn't see in the example nor think it required a hibernate config.  There is none at this moment..